# Callback starts a second instance of my app?

Tags: android, maui

I try to use the [sumup-android-api](https://github.com/sumup/sumup-android-api#uri-call). It works fine until the callback is triggered. It somehow starts a second instance of my app inside the sumup app, doesn't it?

First instance:

[image: first instance]

Second instance inside the sumup-App, have a look at the app-icon.

[image: second instance]

I start the sumup process like this:

```
Launcher.Default.OpenAsync(@"sumupmerchant://pay/1.0?affiliate-key=itsasecret&app-id=dummyapp&total=5.00&currency=EUR&title=1000084564&skip-screen-success=true&callback=renditewebclient://sumup");
```

My `MainActivity.cs` looks like this:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace RenditeBrowser
{
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new[] { Intent.ActionView, Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable }, DataScheme = "renditewebclient", DataHost = "sumup")]
    public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
        {
            if (this.Intent != null)
            {
                Intent intent = this.Intent;
                var action = intent.Action;
                var strLink = intent.DataString;
                if (Intent.ActionView == action && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strLink))
                {
                    if (strLink.Contains("sumup"))
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Intent-Data: " + strLink);
                    }
                }
            }
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the official document about the [Tasks and the back stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack).  And about the [launchMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#ManifestForTasks):

> "standard"

> The default mode. The system creates a new instance of the activity in
> the task it was started from and routes the intent to it. The activity
> can be instantiated multiple times, each instance can belong to
> different tasks, and one task can have multiple instances.

So you can change the launchmode to SingleTask or SingleInstance:

Such as:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask, MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new[] { Intent.ActionView, Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable }, DataScheme = "renditewebclient", DataHost = "sumup")]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
```